# ERROR: MethodError: no method matching zero(::Type{Any})

Tags: julia, nonlinear-functions

I am very new to Julia. I am trying to solve a system of nonlinear equations to find a vector (`p_new`). Below a simplified version of my problem. The issue is that I get this message: `"ERROR: MethodError: no method matching zero(::, Type{Any})"`.  I am not sure whether it is because the initial conditions are not well defined. Thanks in advance!

```
p_1 = [ 1, 2, 2.3]
p_1b = [ 1, 2.2, 2.5]
mgc = [1, 1, 0.5]
theta = 0.8
OW1 = [0 1 0; 1 1 1; 0 0 1]
g = ones(3,1)
function pupdate!(p_1,mgc,theta,OW1)
    delt = p_1.*theta
    delt = 2.718281828459.^delt
    Sp1 = sum(delt)
    sp1 = delt./Sp1
    markup = p_1 .- mgc 
    sp1 .= markup
end
g0 = [p_1b, mgc, theta, OW1]
p_new = nlsolve(pupdate!, g0)
```

Comment: BTW, there are `MathConstants.e` as well as `exp` in `Base`.

Comment: Also you should put spaces around `.*` and `./`. In general you do not use `nlsolve` correctly. I would recommend you to read the examples in https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/NLsolve.jl to see what should be passed as arguments to this function. If you would still have problems please edit your question writing in mathematical terms (not in code) what optimization problem you want to solve and I can help you to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error, and the problem was that my vector representation of the state was incorrect. In your case I encounter a similar situation.

```
julia> g0 = [p_1b, mgc, theta, OW1]
4-element Vector{Any}:
  [1.0, 2.2, 2.5]
  [1.0, 1.0, 0.5]
 0.8
  [0 1 0; 1 1 1; 0 0 1]
```

The fix is quite easy:

```
julia > g0 = p_1b; mgc; theta; OW1[:]]
```

which return a vector.

It also took me some time to get used to Julia's use of `,`, `;` and  , but once you do, it's quite good.

FWIW: I would suggest embracing Julia's multiple dispatch and *not* creating functions `pupdate!` and `gupdate!` but just one function `update!` with two methods.